# Default implicit parameters SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I can't seem to figure out what's the point of having default implicit parameters in SQL (please see the example below), given that SQL is a declarative language. Isn't forcing the parameters a way of assuring more readability? After all, code is meant to be written once and read by humans many times (or at least once).

For example, in PostgreSQL we have the [following syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/queries-table-expressions.html):

```
T1 { [INNER] | { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [OUTER] } JOIN T2 ON boolean_expression
```

The following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 JOIN T2
ON true;
```

implies an inner join meaning it is equal to the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2
ON true;
```

can someone please explain to me the reason behind the idea of default and optional parameters (in our example the implicit type of join) in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax was devised by the SQL standard committee in its wisdom.

Nobody can accuse SQL of being excessively terse, but I guess there were some cases where the option to abbreviate the syntax was deemed appropriate (another case that comes to mind is `CREATE TEMP[ORARY] TABLE`).

You touched the question of readability, and I think it is a valid one. We can probably agree that very terse syntax hampers readability, but so can excessively verbose syntax.

I think that it was mostly a question of taste and judgement on the side of the people who wrote the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to follow.  `INNER` and `OUTER` are not *parameters*.  They are keywords.  The syntax diagram doesn't make this explicit, but SQL supports the following `JOIN` operators:

- `JOIN`
- `INNER JOIN`
- `LEFT JOIN`
- `LEFT OUTER JOIN`
- `RIGHT JOIN`
- `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`
- `FULL JOIN`
- `FULL OUTER JOIN`
- `CROSS JOIN`

These are in pairs, except for the `CROSS JOIN`.  In other words, the `INNER` and `OUTER` are optional.

Why is this the case?  There is little "wisdom" in my opinion in setting the SQL standards.  The standards committee consists (primarily) of industry representatives, from companies that often *have already implemented the functionality*.  The standards then bring it together "compatibly".  So, some members wanted explicit `INNER` and `OUTER`.  Others did not.  The "compromise" is to allow both.

As for your question those queries are equivalent.  But the right way to express the logic eschews the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2;
```